# How to mount shared folder/disk as 755 and not as 700 mode?

Tags: macos, permissions, mount, network-shares, file-permissions

If I mount a time capsule disk (or another AFP, SMB network resource) and look on it with `ls -la` it appears as `drwx------`, so rsync can't access it (even with sudo). How to mount a network resource different than `700` (e.g. `755`)? I'm on OSX (but I would like to know how to reach it generally on unix systems)

Answer (score 0):

Once the disk is mounted, use `chmod 755 mountpoint` as the administrative/root user.

BTW, make sure that the directory being used as the mount point has 755 permissions.  You can verify this by checking the mountpoint when the disk is unmounted.

Comment: `sudo chmod 755 mountpoint` doesn't work - nothing happens